# How can I get Excel 2013 to treat a month name as a name not a date?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a pivot table that displays surnames and counts. In some cases, the person's surname is also the name of a month (ex. August). The pivot table, instead of sorting the name alphabetically like the other entries, puts it at the top of the list. I believe it is treating it as a date. I have tried putting an apostrophe in front of the name and changing the cell format to text, but neither worked. Any suggestions? As a workaround I have entered a period before the last letter of the surname (ex. Augus.t), but obviously that is not ideal. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the header of the column that has August in it, right-click on the down-arrow, then select `More Sort Options`. Then select `More Options` in the resulting dialog. Uncheck the `AutoSort` option, and choose 'No Calculation" for the First key sort order. That caused my sample pivot table (Excel 2013) to stop treating "August" as a special case.

Slight drawback: you'll now have to choose "Sort A to Z" under the down arrow to re-sort the pivot table whenever your data changes.